# How to create a submatch for this expression?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, expression

I am running a regular expression against the DOM to return back an account status from a page.

This is the string on the page:

`<h3>Status</h3><p>Completed</p>`

And this is the Expression I'm currently using
`<h3>Status</h3>[\s\S]*?<p>([\s\S]*?)</p>`

My goal is to only get the Status of "Completed" from this string but not sure on how to do this. I have read a little on submatching; just not sure how to implement it.

Comment: Don't use regex to parse HTML. You could easily use `document.createElement("div")`, set its `innerHTML` with this string, and then traverse it properly. Here's a simple example: http://jsfiddle.net/95Bcu/

Comment: I have over 200 pieces of information that I will be collecting from various pages in our system. I want to make it dynamic so i dont have to hardcode the expressions into the page it self. I want to store the expression and pass it to a function that returns the value. If you know of another way to do this that is dynamic I am open to suggestions.

Comment: Can you give a small example?

Comment: Are you saying that a `<p>` **always** comes after a `<h3>` and will contain the text you want?

Comment: Lets say the website was Stackoverflow's home page.

My tool will say "Select all of the pieces of information you want to collect from the database.

If I chose "Profile Name, # of featured Topics and Total number in Inbox" then I would have an expression for each one of those in the database.

My ie.object navigates to the URL, grabs each of the expressions and runs it against the whole DOM (html). It returns the value of what it is and writes it to excel.

I understand I may need 2-3 functions to strip data out but trying to figure out the best method.

Comment: Ah, so its like a bot, instead of an script executed lively on each page?

Comment: In a sense yeah. Its run by some one for reporting reasons. They just choose what data they want in the report and it gets that data from the pages.

Comment: I see, I guess the info is stored on html files, and not on a real database. (if is on a real database, it would be better to make a backend search engine using SQL queries, and passing the response to the frontend using ajax) Well, then I guess I would create a bash script using sed to get the results and return them as a DSV

Comment: The results are stored in a database I dont have access to. Large company, small internal team that makes tools for Agents. We can see all the data but when a quick report is needed, this is where the tool will come into place so scrape it from the front end view

Answer (score 0):

This will work: `/<h3>Status<\/h3>[\s\S]*<[^>]*>([^<]+)<.*/`

See it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/M7kJ7/

But seriously... use DOM functions for that! Why a regex?

**EDIT**: Example of how you could solve it using DOM functions: http://jsfiddle.net/DycGh/

**EDIT2**: OK, after reading all the comments, I came to the conclusion that you do have valid reason to not access directly the database (you can't! they don't give you access to it)
And you can't use native DOM functions (you are not executing js directly on each page, but instead one central page is going to be used for searching the other pages)
,
However, I still don't think *browser-side* javascript is the correct path.

Using either *server-side* javascript (node.js), or some other language, like perl would be better. And using DOM, by means of a parser, is correct too.

If you choose with the `node.js` path, you can use [node-htmlparser](https://github.com/tautologistics/node-htmlparser). From your node app you'll open each url, get the data using the parser's functions and then construct a json output. Your page will make an ajax request to node, and get its json results, which you will use to create the output.

If you go for perl, you can use [HTML::DOM](http://search.cpan.org/~sprout/HTML-DOM-0.053/lib/HTML/DOM.pm). The rest of the procedure would be similar.

It doesn't has to be perl or node.js, is just the options I know. With php, python or ruby you can do it too. (but you'll have to google for parsers)

But is best if you do it with a server-side script.

Comment: I'm pulling the expressions from a database to make it more dynamic when I have additional things I need to find on the page. If I have a new value, my goal is to jsu make a new expression in the database and then that gets thrown into a function that runs against the dom.

Comment: @CarlHussey So you are storing in your database the raw HTML?

Comment: `var theDocument = objIE.document.documentElement.innerHTML; 

var regexNew = new RegExp(tmpRegEx1, "gi"); //This is where the expression is 

var regexResults = theDocument.match(regexNew);`

Comment: In that case change your html to `<h3>Status</h3><p id="status">Completed</p>` and then do `document.getElementById('status').innerHTML` to get the status. Added an example of that to the answer.

Comment: I have 200+ pieces of information this tool will be gathering info from. Using ieObject it will navigate the to the page and then need to extra that piece of data I am looking for. I am trying to make this dynamic so i figured passing an expression would be best ?

Comment: ahh for some reason you can't change the script that creates the HTML of those pages *or* they are plain static HTML files? It is public? can we see that pages?

Comment: They are internal sites / systems. I am just trying to collect certain pieces of information from the page depending on what is selected by the user. I'm trying to avoid hardcoding it so I want to make a function that I pass an expression or something to it and it runs against the DOM to get the result

Answer (score 0):

`re.match()` returns an array containing the sub-matches for each capture group. So use:

```
var re = new RegExp('<h3>Status</h3>[\s\S]*?<p>([\s\S]*?)</p>');
var match = re.match(str);
var submatch = match[1];
```